# Laravel Eloquent - Model extends other model

Tags: php, laravel

I have a question about extending my own Models eloquent.

In the project I am currently working on is table called `modules` and it contains list of project modules, number of elements of that module, add date etc.

For example:
`id = 1; name = 'users'; count = 120; date_add = '2007-05-05';`

and this entity called `users` corresponds to model `User` (Table - `users`) so that "count" it's number of Users

and to update `count` we use script running every day (I know that it's not good way but... u know).

In that script is loop and inside that loop a lot of if statement (1 per module) and inside the if a single query with count. According to example it's similar to:

```
foreach($modules as $module) {
    if($module['name'] == 'users') {
        $count = old_and_bad_method_to_count('users', "state = 'on'");
    }
}

function old_and_bad_method_to_count($table, $sql_cond) {}
```

So its look terrible.

I need to refactor that code a little bit, because it's use a dangerous function instead of Query/Builder or Eloquent/Model and looks bad.

I came up with an idea that I will use a Models and create Interface `ElementsCountable` and all models that do not have an interface will use the `Model::all()->count()`, and those with an interface will use the interface method:

```
foreach ($modules as $module) {
    $className = $module->getModelName();

    if($className) {
        $modelInterfaces = class_implements($className);
        if(isset($modelInterfaces[ElementsCountable::class])) {
            /** @var ElementsCountable $className */
            $count = $className::countModuleElements();
        } else {
            /** @var Model $className */
            $count = $className::all()->count();
        }
    }
}
```

in method `getModelName()` i use a const map array (table -> model) which I created, because a lot of models have custom table name.

But then I realize that will be a good way, but there is a few records in `Modules` that use the same table, for example `users_off` which use the same table as `users`, but use other condition - `state = 'off'`

So it complicated things a little bit, and there is a right question: There is a good way to extends `User` and add scope with condition on boot?

```
class UserOff extends User
{
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope(function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->where('state', '=', 'off');
        });
    }
}
```

Because I have some concerns if this is a good solution. Because all method of that class NEED always that scope and how to prevent from method `withoutGlobalScope()` and what about other complications?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a good solution to create the `UserOff` model with the additional global scope for this purpose.

I also think the solution I would want to implement would allow me to do something like

```php
$count = $modules->sum(function ($module) {
    $className = $module->getModelName();

    return $className::modulesCount();
}
```

I would create an interface `ModulesCountable` that mandates a `modulesCount()` method on each of the models. The `modulesCount()` method would return either the default count or whatever current implementation you have in `countModuleElements()`.

If there are a lot of models I would probably use a trait `DefaultModulesCount` for the default count, and maybe the custom version too eg. `ElementsModuleCount` if that is consistent.

Comment: Ok, but what about geting a user which is already active from model `UserOff`. I mean for e.g. `UserOff::find(10);` where 10 is active user. You're get a instance of UserOff, but it isn't off. It could be confusing I think.

Comment: You wouldn't get an instance of `UserOff` you would get `null` by design because of the global scope.